# IGDB - How to fetch JSON data from igdb.com? using Axios and nodejs

Tags: node.js, api, axios

I am a beginner programmer, I am using the following code to fetch data from IGDB API.

```
    axios.get('https://api-v3.igdb.com/games', {
    headers: {
        'user-key': 'my-key'
    }
   
}).then(res => console.log(res)).catch(error => console.log(error))
```

Instead of games, its responding a lot of stuff. I want JSON data for games. How can I fetch that? Please help. Documentation is [here](https://api-docs.igdb.com/#about).

Answer (score 0):

Probably with axios response you need to access the `data` object,something like below

```
axios.get('https://api-v3.igdb.com/games', {
    headers: {
        'user-key': 'my-key'
    }
   // use res.data
}).then(res => console.log(res.data)).catch(error => console.log(error))
```